# How to iterate through array of objects and execute a request using react?

Tags: reactjs

i have to execute a request for each object within data.

The data contains details about items with each item being distinguished with id and is like in data_to_loop variable,

```
 let data_to_loop = [
   {
       attributes: 
       {
           after: {…}, 
           before: {…}, 
       }
           id: 71
           read_status: "unread"
    },
    {
        attributes: 
        {
               after: {…}, 
               before: {…}, 
        }
        id: 70
           read_status: "unread"
     },
     .
      .
     ......so on ,,,
]
```

So the above data can have any number of items. so should iterate through each item and execute post request on it. The request is like below,

```
within client file
export function clear_item(id, cancel) {
    return post(`items/${id}/clear`, cancel);
}
```

I have tried something like below,

```
client.clear_item('72')
    .then((request) => {
         console.log("request onclear", request);
});
```

The above is hard coded with item id. this clears that particular item.

How do i do it for all the items in data_to_loop var.

Could someone help me with this. Thanks.

Comment: I suggest looking into Array.map()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method on the `data_to_loop` array and create a request for each object in the array. You can then use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) on this resulting array of promises to add some logic when all requests are complete.

```
Promise.all(
  data_to_loop.map(obj =>
    client
      .clear_item(obj.id)
      .then(request => console.log("request onclear", request))
  )
).then(() => console.log("all requests complete"));
```